# Universal filtering in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

My model has 2 columns: Source System and Target System and I am using the NetworkNavigator custom visual. My goal is to search for a specific system and display all relationships to that system, regardless if it is a source or target in the relationship.

Assume the following 2 records: Source=A Target=B, Source=B Target=C. I would like to search for "B" and see both records (I am using the NetworkNavigator custom visual).

**Is there a way to have one filter that searches in both of my columns at once?** (I am transitioning from Qlik to PBI. In Qlik this works out of the box)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make your network table symmetric by taking the union of the table with itself having the source and target switched.

Try creating a New Table (under Modeling tab) using a formula along these lines:

```
AllNodes = DISTINCT(UNION(SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Network[Source], Network[Target]),
                          SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Network[Target], Network[Source])))
```

Then build your Network Navigator visual based on that table instead of the original and add a slicer on either column of this table to do your filtering.